# Whenever I scope the routes.rb I get an error in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I am trying to implement internationalization as seen in railscasts, and every time I scope my routes file I get the error

```
 No route matches [GET] "/"
```

or the error

```
missing :controller
config/routes.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
config/routes.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Here is my routes.rb file

```
Jensenlocksmithing::Application.routes.draw do
  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", as: "log_out"
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", as: "log_in"

  scope ":locale" do
    get "site/home"
    get "site/about_us"
    get "site/faq"
    get "site/discounts"
    get "site/services"
    get "site/contact_us"
    get "site/admin"
    get "site/posts"

    root :to => 'site#home'
  end

  #match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
  #match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")

  match "/savesort" => 'site#savesort'

  resources :users
  resources :abouts
  resources :sessions
  resources :coupons
  resources :monthly_posts
  resources :reviews

  resources :categories do
    collection { post :sort }
      resources :children, :controller => :categories, :only => [:index, :new, :create,  :new_subcategory]
  end
  resources :products do
    member do
       put :move_up
       put :move_down
   end 
  end
  resources :faqs do
    collection { post :sort }
  end 
end
```

So, why whenever I add the scope ":locale" do end line do I get these errors? It all works fine without. Let me know if you need to see any more code. Thanks guys

**Edit**

In my application controller I have the following:

```
private

def default_url_options(options = {})
  {locale: I18n.locale}  
end
```

Does this do the same thing as the passing the hash in the routes?

**Edit 2**

I changed my route to the following as seen in this gist. 
https://gist.github.com/2322844

So why is the :id part being added to the get route? like this one

```
 about_us_site GET  /sites/:id/about_us(.:format)
```

shouldn't it be something like this

```
 about_us_site GET  /sites/about_us(.:format)
```

Also added my entire routes.rb file and the routes it generates for more information.
https://gist.github.com/2322861

**Answer for anyone interested:**

I changed

```
    get "site/home"
    get "site/about_us"
    get "site/faq"
    get "site/discounts"
    get "site/services"
    get "site/contact_us"
    get "site/admin"
    get "site/posts"

    root :to => 'site#home'
```

to

```
 resources :sites, except: [:new, :edit, :index, :show, :update, :destroy, :create] do  
   collection do  
   get :home  
   get :about_us  
   get :faq  
   get :discounts  
   get :services  
   get :contact_us  
   get :admin  
   get :posts  
 end
```

end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing in a hash should fix your routes:

```
scope "(:locale)", :defaults => { :locale => "en" } do
  resources :sites
end
```

Also, you may want to consider creating a `SitesController` and giving it `members`:

```
resources :sites do
  member do
    get :about_us # Points to /sites/about_us
  end
end
```

- [Rails Guides on Defining Defaults In Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults)

Comment: Look at my edit, should the default_url_options function do the same thing?

Comment: I'm not actually sure. What's the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: I verified that it is indeed adding the default in my application controller. I have changed my routes to the standards as youdefined, but it's adding the :id to the routes. See my edit for details, thanks again

Comment: I ended up going with a collection route rather than a member, because a collection didn't depend on the :id of the site.

Comment: I did get the `locale` routes working, thanks. I just wrapped it around my resources site, and changed the naming of my sitecontroller to sitescontroller and a few other things. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Glad you got everything in order! Good luck with the rest of the project.